# In C is & shorthand for logical and(&&)?

Tags: c, logical-operators

Sometimes I want to do something like this (with i and j being ints).

```
(if i==4 && j==9)
{
   ...
}
```

Where it'll go through the brackets if i equals 4 and j equals 9. I've been using a single ampersand (&) instead of a double one and my code's been compiling and running.

Is it doing the same thing as a double ampersand &&, and if not what has it been doing?

Edit: Oh and I've been doing the same thing with or, using '|' instead of '||'

Comment: No. It is *not* a shorthand although they may often *appear* equivalent. One is a "bitwise AND", one is a "short-circuiting logical AND" (plenty of information using those terms).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably you mean `if (i==4 && j==9)`.

Under the circumstances, changing this from `&&` to `&` shouldn't change *much*. The big thing that'll change is that with `&&`, the `j==9` would only be evaluated if the `i==4` part was true, but with `&`, they'll both be evaluated regardless.

When you have something like `if (x != NULL && x->whatever ...)` you want to ensure that the second part (that dereferences `x`) is only evaluated if `x` is not a null pointer. In your case, however, comparing what appear to be `int`s is unlikely to produce any problems.

It's also possible to run into a problem when you're dealing with something that may produce a value other than `1` to signal `true`. Again, it's not a problem here because `==` will always produce either `0` or `1`. If (for example) you were using `isalpha`, `islower`, etc., from `<ctype.h>`, they're only required to produce `0` or non-zero values. If you combined those with a `&`, you'd get a bit-wise `or` which could produce 0 for two non-zero inputs (e.g., `1 & 2 == 0`, but `1 && 2 == 1`).

When you use bitwise `and` on the results from `==`, you're going to get `0 & 0` or `0 & 1` or `1 & 0` or `1 & 1`. `1 & 1` will yield `1` (true). All the others will yield 0 (false) --- just like `&&` would have.

Comment: +1. `if (x != NULL && x->whatever ...) you want to ensure that the second part (that dereferences x) is only evaluated if x is not a null pointer.` that's good example.

Answer (score 5):

It's performing a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

What it's doing is the expression `i == 4` is equivalent to `1` if `i` is `4` and the same for the RHS (with `j` and `9`, obviously). The `&` operator returns the number where both operands have that bit on.

It works the same as `&&` because `00000001 & 00000001` (slimmed down to a byte for example) is the same. If one is `0` (the condition was false), then the `&` won't see two bits turned on for both operands, and `00000000` is `0`, which is *falsey*.

**However**, do not simply use `&` because it's *one character shorter* or similar. Use it because it expresses what you want to achieve. If it's a logical AND you want, use `&&`.

The same thing applies to `|`, except instead of a resulting bit if each operand has it turned on, it turns it on if either operand has that bit turned on.

Answer (score 2):

A single ampersand does a bitwise AND.  Every bit of the result is set only if both operands have a 1 in that position.

Since comparisons in C return 1 for true and 0 for false, `&` will give the same results as `&&` as long as both operands are comparisons.  But for arbitrary values, it will return seemingly random results.  `1 && 2` is true, but `1 & 2` is false because the binary representations of 1 and 2 have no bits in common.

Answer (score 0):

A single ampersand is called a bitwise and. It is a binary operator that 'ands' two numbers bit by bit.

For instance, if you have two binary numbers, 01100010 and 00011111, your bitwise and will result in 00000010

i==4 returns 1 (true), as does j==9. So, i==4 & j==9 is really just 1 & 1, which evaluates to 1 (true).

Try these examples to see the difference

1) int k = 4 & 6; vs int k = 4 && 6;

2) if(i==4 && 2) vs if(i==4 & 2)

Comment: Ok so what happens if I have the example above with one ampersand. How does "i==4 & j==9" work?